# Cappuccino Redirect

Tags: redirect, cappuccino, objective-j

What would the best practice be to redirect someone to another page in Objective-J (Cappuccino)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally you wouldn't have multiple pages in a Cappuccino application. But assuming you do want the user to leave your app, just use JavaScript. Objective-J is a superset of JavaScript, so it has everything JavaScript does.

```
- (void)redirectTo:(CPString)aLocation
{
    window.location = aLocation;
}

- (void)handler
{
    [self redirectTo:"http://www.google.com"];
}
```